# Obtain Spring bean dependencies @ Runtime

Tags: java, spring

In a spring application, I would like get the object graph structure of a given bean along with the list of dependents(including nested) during runtime.

E.g:

```
public class College {
   private List<Student>
   private List<Staff>
   private List<Department>

  setter Methods....
}

public class Student {
  private List<Subject>;
  private Address;    

 setter Methods....
}
```

Assumption:
* All are injected & wired through spring.
* Want to leverage any API within spring (and hence avoid reflection)

Goal:
* Display the dependency information through UI to the user. Other means to achieve this is to maintain a duplicate copy outside the application (like db, non-spring bean xml) which is ofcourse bad and hence avoided

Comment: Can you tell a little more about what you are trying to accomplish here? And what do you mean with 'object graph structure'?

Comment: You may have a look at the [reflection framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: Hi @ErikPragt, By object structure I mean the bean object that was created by the spring along with its dependencies that exists in memory. In the example above, the whole object structure of the **College** object that exists in memory.

Comment: Well, you'll probably need Reflection like Arun suggests, but how do you know if the list of students is created by Spring or that you constructed it yourself?

Comment: In-case we do not want to make a distinction b/w spring created vs others, is there a way(spring provided functionality) other than we directly using reflection?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `ReaderEventListener` to build the object grahp when the context startup.

For example:

```
public class TrackingReaderEventListener extends EmptyReaderEventListener {

    private Map<String, ComponentDefinition> components = new HashMap<String, ComponentDefinition>();

    @Override
    public void componentRegistered(ComponentDefinition componentDefinition) {
        components.put(componentDefinition.getName(), componentDefinition);
    }

    public Map<String, ComponentDefinition> getComponentMap() {
        return components;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TrackingReaderEventListener listener = new TrackingReaderEventListener();
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new AppContext("applicationContext.xml", listener);
        context.refresh();   // or may be load beans definitions only
    }

}

class AppContext extends ClassPathXmlApplicationContext {

    private ReaderEventListener readerListener;

    public AppContext(String configLocation, ReaderEventListener readerListener) {
        super(new String[] {configLocation} , false);
        this.readerListener = readerListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
        super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
        reader.setEventListener(readerListener);
    }

}
```

Or build them directly from the `BeanFactory`

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory)  context.getBeanFactory();
    String[] beanNames = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        BeanDefinition bd = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
        PropertyValues pvs = bd.getPropertyValues();
        String[]  dependsOn = bd.getDependsOn();
        ...
    }
```