# How to get a list of all unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, autowired

I'd like to register a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` or some such and be able to retrieve a list of all unsatisfied dependencies.

I've tried to look into the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` source code to find some clues but it's a mess.

Hacks like [this example](http://java.dzone.com/tips/automatically-inject-mocks), where they just go over all the registered beans and list all autowired fields don't count. This has many obvious drawbacks (constructor dependency anyone?).

Clarification: I need to be able to determine all unsatisfied dependencies and *their types*. So while getting a list of `BeanDefinitons` one way or another and then using the `getDependsOn()` method will give me a list of unsatisfied dependency names,  but it still leaves me to figure out their type somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ReaderEventListener to build the object graph at context startup.

See here:
[Obtain Spring bean dependencies @ Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524216/obtain-spring-bean-dependencies-runtime)

Comment: will I be able to still add new bean definitions at this point?

Comment: plus I see I will just get all dependencies and will have to find out manually which ones are not satisfied? I don't see how this is better than just getting a list of beans from ListableBeanFactory etc.

Comment: What do you mean by adding new definitions? You'd want to load new beans now? You're right, it's not really better than ListableBeanFactory, but it's an alternative, I though might help you.